# Set the year as prefix in Numbersequences

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, number-sequence

In AX 2012 I want to add the year (e.g. 2011) as prefix in the ID field.

For instance I create a new customer in AX. The ID of this new customer should be like: 2013-00000123

Is it possible to set the year in the segments instead of coding this.

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to specify the version of AX. This is handled differently in AX2012 compared to AX2009, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "*fixed*" solution proposed by Sshaheen don't suit your needs, and you **really** need to get a dynamic value for the year, the only suitable solution if to develop it through X++ code, in the *CustTable* table or class (just find where a new sequence number is obtained).

Anyway, I'll recommend using a constant value on the number sequence, as Sshaheen states.

Comment: Is it possible to get a dynamic value by changing settings of the segments? Can I avoid coding?

Comment: It's not possible, as far as I know. You can find a very detailed documentation about the new numseq framework here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272879.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to [create a new number sequence](http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/53329/279140.aspx) and make two segments, one that is constant (the year 2013), and one that is alphanumeric. Then, go to the AR parameters and set Customers to your new number sequence. However, you would need to do this at the first of every year to change the constant.

Comment: Thanks but I need to get a dynamic value.